# How to add a description to a model managed via ModelAdmin?

Tags: silverstripe

I have a model managed via model admin, I want to add a description below the `gridfield`. Usually this is accomplished by setting `->setDescription('Note in here')`

How do you do this when it is managed via the `ModelAdmin`?

```
<?php

class FormDropdownModelAdmin extends ModelAdmin {

    private static $managed_models = array(
        'HearAboutUsItem'
    );

    private static $url_segment = 'form-dropdown-items';

    private static $menu_title = 'Form Dropdown Items';

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overload the getEditForm method on your ModelAdmin and apply a description to the field.

```
public function getEditForm($id = NULL, $fields = NULL) {
    $form = parent::getEditForm($id, $fields);

    $form->Fields()->fieldByName('HearAboutUsItem')
        ->setDescription('This is my description');
    return $form;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. However I have now added multiple models to this Modeladmin, and when I click on the tab to access another model it throws: `Fatal error: Call to a member function setDescription() on a non-object` - I thought I would be able to just duplicate your code and change the model in the fieldByName('AnotherModel') - but nope didn't work.. Any ideas on how to add a description to each of the managed models within the ModelAdmin?

Comment: Replace 'AnotherModel' with `$this->modelClass`

Comment: That works, but shows the same description for each model. If you wanted a unique description for each model how do you do that?

Comment: A couple of ways: make a `switch($this->modelClass)` and set the description based on different case statements. You could also use the language file system. First, define the different strings in your en/lang.yml file. The entry you're looking for would be $entry = $this->modelClass.".CMSDescription". You'd dynamically load your string with `_t($entry)`. Some examples for using this system are here: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/i18n/#translating-text